# pro-verb: what does "did" refer to in this context?

Tags: reference

In the following article, the underlined 'did' refers to the word 'mature' in the same sentence. But, how about the word 'reach' in the previous sentence? Is it ok to say the word 'did' can also be replaced with 'reach' for having the similar meaning in the context?[image]

Comment: Hi. First, you might want to check the dictionary definition of _reach_ - see the second listed verbal sense [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/reach). Questions here are expected to demonstrate some research effort on the asker's part, not least as that research can help potential answerers. Take a look at [how to ask](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Also consider if your question might be better suited to [English Language Learners](//ell.stackexchange.com) - generally, if a question would be trivial to a native speaker, that's a better place to go.

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Comment: Please do not post text as graphics. It discriminates against those using screen readers, and cannot be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *did* substitutes for the main verb in the same sentence (*mature*).
*Did* can't substitute for a verb of the previous sentence (for example, *reach* in the sentence from the answer) unless it is used immediately after the full stop before another verb.
For example:

> "I saw Ann yesterday."
>    "So did I. She looked a bit frustrated."
>    "Did she?"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation. I got a big help. :)